# How can I tell Music for iPad to play all of an artist's songs without making a playlist?

Tags: ipad, ios, music, ipod.app

I want to play all of an artist's songs that I have, on multiple albums. Making a playlist seems overkill. This was never an issue in iOS 4, as there was a track-shaped option for shuffle play.

Please note that I want something that *always* works, so simply "pressing play while on an artist's page" won't do the trick as sometimes a song is currently "playing" already.

I'm running iOS 5.1.

Comment: I assume you excluded the only option available. At least that's what I usually do: Navigate to the artist, select "All Songs" and then "Shuffle"...

Comment: @Patrix That only worked in iOS 4 and earlier, in iOS 5, there's no option to do that. "This was never an issue in iOS 4, as there was a track-shaped option for shuffle play."

Comment: Hmm, probably I'm not understanding what you want to accomplish. See http://d.pr/CLmV for a way which works for me in iOS 5.x.

Comment: That's where it was in iOS 4, but it's not there on an iPad :(

Comment: Seems to have gone indeed (didn't realize your question was iPad related).

Answer (score 1):

Not obvious at all, but:

- Tap `My Music` from bottom nav.
- Tap the red filter menu selection that's located roughly upper central on the screen, just below the `Recently Added` section.

  - The filter menu should say `Artists` or `Albums` or `Songs` etc. Choose your desired filter option (`Artists` in this case).
  - The list items below the filter will update.
- **Tap the list item's avatar** (*tap the artist photo*, in this case). **Do not tap the list item's text** (*the artist's name*), unless you want instead to navigate into sublists.
- A queue will begin playing from your selection.

  - If you already had a queue, the old queue will be replaced with this new queue.
  - The first song in the queue will not be random, even if you had shuffle enabled.
- An almost-too-skinny-to-tap bar will appear at the bottom of your screen.

  - Tap it to view the current song, to access shuffle and continuous buttons, and to preview the queue (menu icon to the right of the fast-forward button).
- Complain to http://apple.com/feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Select the artist of choice, then hit the play button. Selecting a song in any of the albums plays only that album.

Comment: Ahem. "Please note that I want something that always works, so simply 'pressing play while on an artist's page' won't do the trick as sometimes a song is currently 'playing' already."